# map с тремя элементами в качестве ключа

Tags: c++

Хочу создать словарь с тремя элементами, но не знаю как это сделать. В качестве ключа хочу передавать `pair<string, string>, string`, а в качестве значения обычный `int`. Возможно ли создать такой словарь? Если да, то как добавлять туда элементы и как производить поиск?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: Создавайте класс-ключ, содержащий `pair<string, string>, string` создавайте `std::map` с этим ключом и значением `int`. Никаких особенностей добавления туда элементов или поиска значений в данном случае нет.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за совет. Видимо то что нужно, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Как и подсказал @Harry решил использовать `tuple`:

```
map<tuple < pair<string, string>, string>, int> triple_combo_map; // создаю словарь 
tuple < pair<string, string>, string> tup_for_map;
pair<string, string> pr(pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]); // создаю пару
tup_for_map = make_tuple(pr, pairs_vec_all[n]);
triple_combo_map[tup_for_map] = 1; // кладу tuple в словарь и присваиваю к примеру значение 1
```

Comment: "Найдите десять отличий": `pair<pair<string,string>,string>`, `tuple<pair<string,string>,string>`, `tuple<string,string,string>`.

Comment: Понял, что имеете ввиду, возможно можно было и по-другому сделать, но пишу как мне удалось